# We need a better subtitle

Tags: feature-request

> Same thing as https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/change-the-sites-subtitle

When a question is migrated away from chemistry.stackexchange.com, the following is shown:

[image]

The subtitle of the site (currently “active researchers, academics, and students”) should be changed to something specific to chemistry so that the migration message makes more sense. After all, this is not StackExchange's only site for active researchers, academics, and students.

IMO, it ought to be `researchers, academics, and students of chemistry` (Use of Oxford comma debatable, Physics doesn't use it).

Thoughts? Suggestions? [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the need for “active” in “active researchers”. Other than that, I'm fine with your suggestion.

Comment: Yep, changed. I'd just copied the existing one and tacked on a "chemistry".

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this seems good. If I had one quibble it would be whether to add a more general noun like "users" - `active researchers, academics, students, and users of chemistry` - for the people filling their sheds with noxious fumes at home.

Comment: I dunno.. One doesn't "use" chemistry, really. Anyway, this will only show up in the migration messages so we don't need to specify every bit of our audience.